# INT to STRING conversion in python

Tags: python

I am unable convert int to `string` using `str()`.
Everywhere on internet I found `str()` used to convert `int` to `string`.

I tried to run this on **jupyter notebook**

My Code:

```
num=23
string=str(num)
```

**Error:**

```
TypeError  Traceback (most recent call last)
ipython-input-24-63bcf2e7ab44> in <module>
       1 num=23
 ----> 2 string=str(num)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: Do you have a variable in your code named `str`?

Comment: yes I found variable name str.

Comment: `str` is a global built-in, so if it's redefined anywhere, you're overwriting that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somewhere earlier on, you did:

```
str = 'somestr goes here'
```

Never name a variable `str`; it causes this problem. You can correct it for now with:

```
del str
```

but the solution in the future is to never use `str` as a variable name.